# Are we able to write data and read data using Firebase when we are offline from unity

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, unity-game-engine

- i am using latest version unity and firebase.
- I need to use offline features of latest firebase in unity.
- Is it possible to read and write data offline.
- Once we read or write data or make any changes to local and when we become online, will the changes get implemented in the main server

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

Most Firebase bindings for Unity wrap the underlying SDK for iOS and Android, in which case it should be fairly easy to expose the disk persistence APIs.

The Firebase Database SDK for Unity follows a different model, where most of the code is actually written in C# directly. While this is great in many cases, it means that we decided to not implement disk persistence in C#.

Note that Firebase's network resilience *will* work on Unity. So as long as the app stays active, Firebase will continue functioning if the network connection drops. In that case it serves any reads from its cache and keeps a queue of pending writes. But there currently is not support for disk persistence, which would allow the cache and queue to survive app restarts.

Comment: Hmmm.... on second thought: I wonder why this isn't documented for Unity. I also don't see the method to enable disk persistence in the reference doc. I'm going to ask around and will report back.

Comment: Meanwhile can u please provide any documents other than firebase docs telling how to write and read data from from firebase throuh unity @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: It turns out I was wrong in my initial assessment: disk persistence is currently not supported in the Unity SDK. Sorry about that. I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). I've done this already, but more votes never hurt.

Comment: If I perform a write, will that write be served for reads out of a local cache during the time the network is unavailable? Deletes? Changes?

Comment: Yes. While the app is active, it'll keep both active data (that you have a listener too, or set to keep synced) in memory and keep a queue of pending writes. Read operations will be served from that combination, ensuring a consistent view. A thing to note here is that security rules are only enforced server-side, so your client-side code might temporarily see invalid data (according to your security rules) and needs to handle this accoringly.